# Is this a good way to define a global instance of an struct in c++?

Tags: c++, global-variables

So I want to store a list of structs that contains rgb values, so I can use them as constants.

This is what I have now, but I'm not sure if there is a better way

```
// color.hpp
#pragma once

struct Color {
  unsigned char r, g, b;
  Color(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
};

extern const Color WHITE;

// color.cpp
#include "color.hpp"

Color::Color(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
    : r(r), g(g), b(b){};

const Color WHITE(255, 255, 255);
```

So the idea is that I can include "color.hpp" anywhere and I can use the same instance of WHITE across different files.

Comment: I think the way you are doing it is acceptable. However I don’t think you need to declare extern for Color WHITE. You are including your color.hpp in color.cpp and therefore the declaration of WHITE will be accessible in color.cpp

Comment: but I want to be able to use color.hpp in more files

Comment: I see. You even wrote it in your question. So in that case extern is fine.